# How to login using SQLite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I have a working API that allows me to login successfully.
However, I want to be able to store my login details into my offline database (SQLite)
If the app is offline, I want to be able to use the store login details in SQLite to login.
Below is my code
Future login() async {
final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

```
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  // No internet connection, attempt offline login
  final userLoginDetails =
      await DatabaseHelper.instance.getUserLoginDetails();

  if (userLoginDetails != null && userLoginDetails.isNotEmpty) {
    final user_id = userLoginDetails['user_id'];
    final email = userLoginDetails['email'];
    final password = userLoginDetails['password'];

    // You can then use this data for offline login
    // Example: Send a request to your local authentication system
    // For demonstration purposes, we'll check if the email and password match
    if (email == email.text && password == password.text) {
      // Offline login successful, navigate to the appropriate page
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LnadingPage(user_id: user_id),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Show an error message for incorrect credentials
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Login Error'),
            content: Text('Invalid email or password.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  } else {
    // No saved user login data, prompt the user to connect to the internet
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('No Saved Login Data'),
          content: Text('Please connect to the internet to log in.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
} else {
  // There is an internet connection, proceed with online login
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://is.danco.com/all/data/login.php'),
    body: {
      'email': email.text,
      'password': password.text,
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data['status'] == 'success') {
      final user_id = data['user_id'];

      // Save user login data to SQLite
      await DatabaseHelper.instance.insertUserLoginDetails({
        'user_id': user_id,
        'email': email.text,
        'password': password.text,
      });
      // Print the saved data
      print('User login details saved to SQLite:');
      print('User ID: $user_id');
      print('Email: ${email.text}');
      print('Password: ${password.text}');

      // Online login successful, navigate to the appropriate page
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LnadingPage(user_id: user_id),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Online login failed, show an error message
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Login Error'),
            content: Text(data['message']),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  } else {
    // Handle network errors or server issues
    // You can display an appropriate error message to the user
  }
}
```

}